# Sharepoint Web Service: Update Content Type of Office-based XML Files

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

We have files in a SharePoint O365 library that need a custom Content Type programmatically set from an Excel spreadsheet.  The content types are enabled in the library.  The spreadsheet contains the file names along with the content type to assign.  This is part of a migration project from Notes.

I'm using web services from Excel (MSXML2.XMLHTTP, UpdateListItems) and it's working fine on 90% of our files, except for Office XML-based documents such as: xlsx, docx, pptx, xlsm, et al.  For some reason, I'm unable to update the content type via web services for these files.  The older 2003 to 2007 Office files such as xls, doc and ppt work just fine.

I can change the content type manually for these files in the library but there are 17,000 of them (across 200+ sites) so a manual solution is not ideal.  When I change the type manually, then test web services to change it back to Document (the default), it works.  I even tried changing the default of the library to the value I need to set, but no luck.  Since the code is working for most of the files, just not these types, I'm not sure posting the code would matter, but if you want to see anything, let me know.

Any help on how to assign content type to Office XML-based documents, using web services, would be appreciated.

**Update:** 
I should mention that even though the content type is not being set, web service response does not generate an error code/message. I have validated the XML for the UpdateListItems request and it shows the correct content type is sent, just not set for these file types.

**Fixed:** 
I can't "Answer" my own question within the first 8 hours but I have resolved this, by accident.  We have a Managed Metadata column (Term Set) as well that I was populating at the same time.  I removed the managed metadata lines from the XML request and the content type populated.

It seems for these Office XML-based files, you have to update each field separately; not within the same update request and in a specific order too.  I had to populate the content type first and then send another update request to populate the managed meta data column.  It's odd other files did not have this issue.

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that it is after 8 hours, officially closing the topic.  See my update under "fixed" in the original post.